# Increase loading speed of frequently used webpages in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview in my Android application which will display webpages of 1 particular website only and I want the webpage to be loaded efficiently. So is there any way to get the page loading efficiency improved by means of techniques like caching or something else so that the URL loading is in the most optimized way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to load web page efficiently is to cache it.
You can write code as below:

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); 

//This part will load the web page if the network is not available.
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
     webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
    }

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com" );
```

The method isNetworkAvailable() checks for an active network connection:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Finally, don't forget to add the following three permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```